# how to check textfield validation in swift when button performs dismiss segue?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

I try to perform segue & text field validation on the action of a button. but it performs dismiss segue without validation.
i am new for ios & swift.

Comment: have you got solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a global Bool variable**

```
var pass=true;
```

**In your button action**

```
@IBAction func Button_Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    if txt_out.text==""   //txt_out will be your UITextField outlet
    {
        pass=false;
    }
    else
    {
        pass=true;
    }
}
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return pass;
}
```

Or  you can directly put validation of `UITextField` in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if txt_out.text==""
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```